# Run program not as administrator

Tags: windows, runas

How can I run a program **not** as Administrator?

I already tried

```
runas /user:guest notepad
```

But I need to provide a password and I don't know it.

p.s.: I only have the default console and PowerShell available.

Answer (score 3):

You are running a Server Core edition of Windows?

1. First you need to enable and set the
   password of the guest user. You
   can do that using this command:`net user guest *` .
2. And then you can use the run as command: `run as /user:guest notepad`.And then enter the password you set in step 1

Please notice: The guest account is by default disabled. You have to enable it first using this command. You also need administrator privileges to be able to do this.

```
net user guest /active:yes
```

Answer (score 1):

`runas` will always prompt for a password, but if the account has no password (like Guest) you can just leave it blank and hit enter.  The program should run anyway.

If the account you're trying to run as has a password, and you don't know it, you're out of luck.  But if you already have administrator access, you can either change that password or create a new user with your desired privilege level to run the command.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to automate the password entry, and this is intentional; see [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041129-00/?p=37183).

Comment: There *is* a way to automate it, using `/savecred`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run as the current user, but under a different trust level, without needing to enter your password again:

1. Start `cmd.exe` as Administrator (as you normally do).
2. Call `runas /showtrustlevels` You will get something like:

   > The following trust levels are available on your system:
   >   0x20000 (Basic User)
3. Now call `runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "cmd.exe"`
4. You will now get a new Command Prompt window called *cmd.exe (running as DOMAIN\Username with restricted privileges)*
5. You can now use this window to run any command without escalation.

You can also run other commands without escalation at step 3. For example: `runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "notepad.exe"`